# What is the difference between Query builder, find and findone in typeorm?

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

I have used a query in typeorm using query builder as:

```
getManager().CreateQueryBuilder(class_name_from_entity_file, 'xyz').select('column_name').where('active_status=1').execute()
```

This is giving me proper output but I have been suggested to use 'find' instead.
Now I have changed my query to:

```
getManager().find(class_name_from_entity_file,
{
  select:['column_name'],
  where: {
          active_status: 1
          }
}
```

both of these queries are giving me the same output so what is the difference between query builder and find? please tell me about findone too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think createQueryBuilder is control data output better than find or findOne. We use leftJoin to handle relations instead pass relation into find.
And with createQueryBuilder, we handle groupBy but find is not provide groupBy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).